# No display in update GUI on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, updates

Every time I click the update button in the Software Updater app in Ubuntu 20.04 I have no display, and I can't upgrade my software. It displays all the packages to be updated, but when I trigger the update it shows no progress bar as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Could you open a terminal and type `sudo apt update`, then update your question to show what messages are coming back? You’re probably getting an error somewhere that the application isn’t capturing very well …